# c# webclient NetworkCredentials in Nodejs

Tags: c#, node.js, http

I have a c# .net Client with this Code:

```
using(WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
    string serialisedData = "";
    serialisedData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myData);
    client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(config.UserData.Username, config.UserData.Password);
    byte[] responsebyte = client.UploadData(config.ServerAddress, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(serialisedData));
}
```

That Client sends data to my nodejs Server. 
Nodejs Code:

```
var http = require('http');

var _server = http.createServer(_listener);
_server.listen(1234);

console.log( 'started' );

function _listener(req, res) {
  let data = []
  req.on('data', chunk => {
    data.push(chunk)
  })
  req.on('end', () => {
    data = Buffer.concat(data);
    var dataString = new Buffer.from(data).toString("utf-8");
    const data = JSON.parse(dataString);
    // data has all the data from the c# object "myData"
    res.write('response')
    res.end()
  })
}
```

But how can I access the credentials of this connection?

---

This is how I can Access the credentials in c#:

```
HttpListener listener = new HttpListener();
listener.Prefixes.Add($"https://+:{Config.Port}/");
listener.AuthenticationSchemes = AuthenticationSchemes.Basic;
listener.Start();
for (; ; )
{
    Console.WriteLine("Listening...");
    IAsyncResult result = listener.BeginGetContext(new AsyncCallback(DoWork), listener);
    result.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne();
    result = null;
}

private void DoWork(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
{
    HttpListener listener = (HttpListener)asyncResult.AsyncState;
    HttpListenerContext context = listener.EndGetContext(asyncResult);
    HttpListenerBasicIdentity identity = (HttpListenerBasicIdentity)context.User.Identity;
    // identity has the credentials

}
```

---

Edit: I cant change the c# Code anymore. So only nodejs solutions are needed

Edit2: The headers also have no Auth or Authentification property…

Edit3: I cant even find if other location exists except the header for credentials/authentification. But this must be possible right? I mean c# can somehow read this stuff from somewhere…

Any Idea what I can try to find the credentials?

Comment: Still no one a clue or how I could search for it? I think it has something to to with "req.on(...)".

Comment: it should be in the headers, did you thoroughly check if the headers indeed not contain an 'authorization' property?

Comment: @stranded I think so. [Screenshot from debuging](https://i.imgur.com/ebeXSv7.png). I also tried thinks like `req.headers['authorization']` or `req.headers['auth']` and something with ".get('authorization')"...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make your C# client to send its networkCredentials as HTTP Basic Authentication to your Nodejs server; the server [should return a response whose header contains a HTTP 401 Unauthorized status and a WWW-Authenticate field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication) if the request does not contain the Authorization header. This will cause your C# client retry the POST with Authorization header.

This process it is called [Authentication challenge](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Authentication) in case you want to search for more info.

There are serveral packages that does that for you; like [http-auth](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-basic-auth) or you can code it by hand (it is not very hard as it is just a matter of checking the existence of the Authorization header in the request and, if there is none or incorrect credentials, make a 401 response with a WWW-Authenticate field)

i.e. from the top of my head:

```
var http = require('http');

var _server = http.createServer(listener);
_server.listen(1234);

console.log('started');

function listener(req, res) {

  if (!req.headers.authorization) {
    res.statusCode = 401;
    res.statusMessage = 'Unauthorized';
    res.setHeader('WWW-Authenticate', 'Basic');
    res.end();
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide me a example how to write this response? I know how to response with the code only but how to make a WWW-authenticate? `res.status(401).end()`.

Comment: @LastChar23 more or less like in my answer... do not forget to also check incorrect authorizations...

Comment: @LastChar23 I strongly recomend you to not do it by hand and reuse some well know package for this. It could be a lot of nuances to worry about that could cause bugs, crashes and/or security flaws in your app. Things like header sizes, charsets, special or non printable characters, etc...

Comment: `req.getHeader()` and `res.statusMessage()` are not a function.

Comment: `res.status` is also not a function. something is wrong here I guess..